# Python Giving Timeseries Error AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'inferred_freq'

Tags: python, time-series, arima

I'm working with TimeSeries in python with data that looks like this:

```
Day Revenue
2   0.000793
3   0.825542
4   0.320332
5   1.082554
```

Note: It starts on day 2 because day 1 was 0, so I removed it.

I receive an error that says AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'inferred_freq'

```
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(df_log)
model = ARIMA(df_log, order=(2,1,2))
results = model.fit(disp=-1)
plt.plot(df_log_shift)
plt.plot(results.fittedvalues, color='red')
```

With that error, I tried

```
decomposition = seasonal_decompose(df_log, freq ="d")
```

and am now receiving this error: TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Any ideas?